# How to scrape from a list of links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a list of links which also have some `interesting urls`:

```
start_urls = ['link1.com', 'link2.com', 'link3.com', ...,'linkN.com']
```

Using scrapy, how can I get?:

```
'link1.com'   'extracted1.link.com'
'link2.com'   'extracted2.link.com'
'link3.com'   'extracted3.link.com'
...
'linkN.com'    'extractedN.link.com'
```

Since I am new with scrapy I tried this just for one link:

```
class ToySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toy"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.example.com/"]
    start_urls = ['link1.com']


    def parse(self, response):

        for link in response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]"):
            item = ToyItem()
            item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
            item['interesting_link'] = link
            yield item
```

However, this returned me:

```
{'link': 'extracted1.link.com',
 'name': <Selector xpath=".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]" data='<a href="extracted1.link.com'>}
```

How can I do the above for all the elements of `start_urls` and return the following list:

```
[
{'link': 'extracted1.link.com',
     'name': 'link1.com'},
{'link': 'extracted2.link.com',
     'name': 'link2.com'},
{'link': 'extracted3.link.com',
     'name': 'link3.com'},
....
{'link': 'extractedN.link.com',
     'name': 'linkN.com'}
]
```

**UPDATE**

After trying @Granitosaurus answer which is for returning `NaN` for links who do not have: `response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")` I did:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")
    if not links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = 'NaN'
        item['name'] = response.url
        return item

    for links in links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = links.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        item['name'] = response.url  # <-- see here
    yield item

    list_of_dics = []
    list_of_dics.append(item)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dics)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)
```

However, instead of returning `(*)`:

```
'link1.com'   'NaN'
'link2.com'   'NAN'
'link3.com'   'extracted3.link.com'
```

I got:

```
'link3.com'   'extracted3.link.com'
```

How can I return `(*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve current url your spider is crawling from `response.url` attribute:

```
start_urls = ['link1.com', 'link2.com', 'link3.com', ...,'linkN.com']

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")
    if not links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = None
        item['name'] = response.url
        return item
    for links in links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = links.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        item['name'] = response.url  # <-- see here
        yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also have another issue... I noted that some `linksN.com` do not have any: `".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]"`. How to return: `linkN, NaN` for such instances?

Comment: @tumbleweed You can just check whether there are any links found, see my edit :)

Comment: Thank you very much, could you check my update?.. I did not understood how to return `NaN` for the values for websites where the spider did not find the `response`

Comment: @tumbleweed there's an issue with the part that writes to csv. If you need csv output look into [Feed Exports](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) or simply run with `--output` or `-o` flag, like: `scrapy crawl myspider -o output.csv`

Comment: Thanks again.. The problem is that just for see the output I did: `to_csv()`.  I will manipulate more the dataframe, that's the reason I can not use `-o` flag... Probably I will open this issue in another question